# Python mechanize form dropdown error

Tags: python, mechanize

I have this code:

```
br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr=0)

br.form['mydropdown'] = 1
r = br.submit()
print r1.read()
```

The HTML of the form which I try to submit is:

```
<select name="mydropdown">
<option value="1">Cake</option>
<option value="2">Apple</option>
<option value="3">Muffin</option>
```

Why I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***", line 9, in <module>
    br.form['dropdown'] = 1
  File "***", line 2782, in __setitem__
    control.value = value
  File "***", line 1977, in __setattr__
    self._set_value(value)
  File "***", line 1993, in _set_value
    elif len(value) > 1:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: You should tell us that which line is which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse your choice like this:

```
br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr=0)

br.form['mydropdown'] = ["1"]
r = br.submit()
print r.read()
```

NOTE: you have `r1` (not `r`) in `print`